# Request permission to send PUSH notifications in Compose and Android 13

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-permissions, side-effects

A slightly non-trivial task: the project goes to MVI + orbit and a task has appeared to request permission to send push notifications. But the question is, what is the best way to do it? Conditionally, a dialog appears in which there are 2 buttons "Cancel" and "Settings". When the user clicks on "Settings" -> it must be transferred to the device settings to activate PUSH notifications. If the user has allowed notifications, then we do some action. The problem is that when you click on "Settings", a method is called from the ViewModel and from there the postSideEffect, in which a request to allow push notifications should already be made. How can I do that? Thank you in advance!

P.S. It is also necessary to somehow keep track that the user already has permission and not call up a dialog that offers to get it.

My code:

```
viewModel.collectSideEffect { sideEffect ->
    when (sideEffect) {
    ...
    SideEffect.OpenSettings -> {
         // write logic here and somehow save in state information that permission has been received
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: "request permission to send push notifications" -- what do you mean by this?

Comment: @CommonsWare It is necessary for the user to go to the application settings screen and give permission to push

Comment: Android has no mechanism to "send push notifications" as part of the OS or SDK. If you are referring to the `POST_NOTIFICATIONS` permission, that is unrelated to any sort of "send" or "push" concept. If you mean you are sending push messages via Firebase Cloud Messaging, I am not aware of any Android system permissions involved in that, beyond the `INTERNET` permission (which does not need to be requested at runtime). This is why I asked what you mean by "send push notifications".

Comment: @CommonsWare POST_NOTIFICATION permission interests me in this case

Comment: @CommonsWare I don't know how to explain it clearly to you. This does not apply to FCM, the user needs to conditionally set the toggle switch that "he will allow receiving notifications" (from our back). Here's how to get this permission to send it to the settings and ask to turn it on? And also subscribe that the user has really enabled the permission

Comment: There is quite a bit already written about requesting runtime permissions in a Compose UI app, such as [this](https://medium.com/@cherfaoui_dev/handle-runtime-permissions-in-jetpack-compose-fc678b8b4a62), [this](https://vtsen.hashnode.dev/how-to-request-android-runtime-permissions-using-jetpack-compose), [this](https://www.composables.co/blog/permissions), and [this](https://semicolonspace.com/jetpack-compose-request-permissions/).

Comment: There are also various libraries that may simplify the process, such as [this](https://github.com/dawidraszka/compose-permission-handler), [this](https://github.com/PatilShreyas/permission-flow-android), and [this](https://github.com/ygorluizfrazao/composed-permissions). `POST_NOTIFICATIONS` is no different than other runtime permissions, so those materials should help!